# How read files making a filter?

Tags: c#, regex, filter, directory

I need to make a read into some directories, the problem is I need make a filter by the name of file.

Example: `"1000123107.jpg"`, `"1700123107.jpg"`, `"1005123101.jpg"`, `"1077123107.jpg"`, I need get the images that end with the character `"7.jpg"` in this case: only `"1000123107.jpg"`, I try with this:

```
string[] filePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
     filePath + "\\", "*7.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But not work, because that get also other images that have a `"7"` at begin or in the middle.
(`"1000123107.jpg"` and `"1700123107.jpg"` and `"1077123107.jpg"`) so thats is wrong!!

I only need return `"1000123107.jpg"`.

Please somebody tell me how can I do?

thanks.

Comment: This might sound stupid but your sorting criterias are a little bit weird. Why not allow sevens on any other position as long as they're the last character as well?

Comment: no matter that the name has other 7, if it matters that ends 7.jpg

Comment: Then I don't understand this statement: `But not work, because that get also other images that have a "7" at begin or in the middle. ("1000123107.jpg" and "1700123107.jpg" and "1077123107.jpg") so thats is wrong!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
var fileList = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles().Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^7]*7.jpg$")).ToList();
```

Maybe this could help.

Comment: no matter that the name has other 7, if it matters that ends 7.jpg, because other file images has 7, but I only need return the images that END in "7.jpg"

Comment: try this it will give you the result you want. It is tried and tested under **.net 3.5**

Comment: That is good, thats work now!! so one question, I need give a directory for example: "c:\Directory" inside of this path I have subdirectories "c:\Directory\Sub1", "c:\Directory\Sub2", "c:\Directory\Sub3" and inside of this are the images, with DirectoryInfo I can't read the subdirectories, how can I do?

Comment: @ale **OK Try this** var fileList = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^7]*7.jpg$")).ToList();

Comment: use star dot star please instead of dot only

Comment: How can I convert that type of list "var fileList", into a List<string>?

Comment: why do you need the list<string> it is the better version it is the list<FileInfo>. You can get more information about the file. Do you have any specific reason to do so?

Answer (score 2):

So far you have a list of files ending in "7.jpg".  To filter out files having 7 other places in the filename use the regex:

```
^[^7]*7\.jpg$
```

(note my initial answer did not include the ^ and $ at the start and end, which you need to use to avoid spurious matches)

Comment: FreeAsInBeer's expression is better. Yours would match things like 100000000000007.jpg.111 and other weird things

Comment: no matter that the name has other 7, if it matters that ends 7.jpg

Comment: @ale Huh?  In your examples you said `"1077123107.jpg"` for example is wrong, but it does end in `"7.jpg"`.  Could you please be clearer?

Comment: @Dmitrij Golubev the question stated: "I only need return `"1000123107.jpg"`".  Since many of the other example files had a 7 at the end I assumed the distinguishing characteristic was that they had 7's elsewhere.  I must admit that I am a little confused by now, and I am hoping for a clarification of the question.

Comment: @sverre: Yes! Sorry, my mistake. In question: "_need get the images that end with the character '7.jpg'_"

Answer (score 2):

Your current regular expression only requires that it end with "7.jpg". It seems that you want to filter for only files that have a single "7" and it's at the very end of the filename. You could use regex like so:

```
^[^7]*7.jpg$
```

Here's how this breaks down:

```
^        - Start of the line.
[^7]*    - Allow any number of characters that are not sevens.
7.jpg    - Ensure that there is a 7 at the end of the filename.
$        - End of the line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text2re](http://txt2re.com/), a free web-based "regex by example" generator. Post your string values there and it will return you combination of regex to pick. Try your own, that's the best way to go about it. This will help you varieties of regular expression to test.

Comment: The 90's called. They want their HTML codez back. How about using something a little more modern: [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: neahh, text2re is much more customizable and detailed.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I do believe you're right. It's more like the Linux of regex, where as RegExr is the Windows of regex. I'll have to look further into this; it seems that it would be a good supplementary tool for regex. RegExr still works for me in 95% of cases.